# Set the version of a .jar application using Processing (Java)

Tags: java, version, processing

I've created an application (called Countdown) with Processing (Java). I exported the application as a .jar-file. If I run it on Mac OS X and click in the top left (on the titlebar) "About Countdown" it shows me a screen with the app's icon and underneath it says "Version 1.0 (1.0)".

[image: This is a screenshot]

How do I change the version of the application in the Processing sketch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the manifest of the jar. You can edit your manifest following the instructions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html).

You can also use [JarMatey](http://staticvoidgames.com/JarMatey/) to set the version number yourself upon export.

(Full disclosure: I'm the author of JarMatey.)